# stacktrace.log file(which is in the target folder of Grails Project) data got deleted

Tags: grails

There is a `stacktrace.log` file in the `target` directory of the Grails project.
Due to its growing size (stacktrace.log), I had to delete the data in the file.

After running the project again and again I am not getting any logs in the `stacktrace.log` file.

How can `stacktrace.log` be populated again?

Comment: Make more programming mistakes that cause exceptions.

Comment: Still with the empty file.